# Trouble editing and saving and XML file using PowerShell

Tags: xml, powershell

I’m relatively new to PowerShell and I'm having issues creating a script to modify and save an XML file (web.config) using PowerShell. The Structure of the XML file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
       <add key="Password" value="Test1234" />
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

I have tried numerous approaches on trying to get powershell to edit the Password Value and save it again but non are working. My latest being:

```
$webConfig = "Z:\TEMP\Web.config"
$doc = new-object System.Xml.XmlDocument
$doc.Load($webConfig)
$doc.get_DocumentElement()."appSettings".WebAdminPassword.value = "$Password"
$doc.Save($webConfig)
```

the variable $Password is a Random 15 character password being generate earlier in the script. Can anyone advise where im going wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$xml = [xml]@'
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <configuration>
   <appSettings>
        <add key="Password" value="Test1234" />
   </appSettings>
 </configuration>
 '@

$xml.configuration.appSettings.add | Where {$_.Key -eq 'password'} |
                                     Foreach {$_.value = 'newpassword'}
$xml.Save()
```

As far as I can see, there is no element or attribute named WebAdminPassword.

Comment: Excellent Thank you so much you resolved my issue! There was no attribute WebAdminPassword this was from the the other file i was trying to edit. Thankyou for help